# BeginSend taking too long till callback

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm using the asynchronous methos BeginSend and I need some sort of a timeout mechanism. What I've implemented works fine for connect and receive timeouts but I have a problem with the BeginSend callback. Even a timeout of 25 seconds is often not enough and gets exceeded. This seems very strange to me and points towards a different cause.

```
  public void Send(String data)
    {
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            client.NoDelay = true;
            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            IAsyncResult res = client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);

            if (!res.IsCompleted)
            {
                sendTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(SendTimeoutCallback, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("No connection to target! Send");
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sendTimeoutflag, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            // the flag was set elsewhere, so return immediately.
            return;
        }
        sendTimeoutflag = 0; //needs to be reset back to 0 for next reception
        // we set the flag to 1, indicating it was completed.

        if (sendTimer != null)
        {
            // stop the timer from firing.
            sendTimer.Dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            ef.updateUI("Sent " + bytesSent.ToString() + " bytes to server." + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SendTimeoutCallback(object obj)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sendTimeoutflag, 2, 0) != 0)
        {
            // the flag was set elsewhere, so return immediately.
            return;
        }

        // we set the flag to 2, indicating a timeout was hit.

        sendTimer.Dispose();
        client.Close(); // closing the Socket cancels the async operation.
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to the target has been lost! SendTimeoutCallback");
    }
```

I've tested timeout values up to 30 seconds. The value of 30 seconds has proved to be the only one never to time out. But that just seems like an overkill and I believe there's a different underlying cause.Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: The documentation sez: "The BeginSend method starts an asynchronous send operation to the remote host established in the Connect, BeginConnect, Accept, or BeginAccept method."  So by that definition we know this is NOT related to a session connection time.  Rather this is directly related to data being sent and received on the wire.  If you run a wireshark trace you can pinpoint which side is having delays, other wise it's a guessing game.  (Is it the client side or is it the host side).  In addition its truly Asynchronous why does the program care? Just ignore it if timeout is exceeded.

Comment: Says what? I've been through it but maybe I've missed something

Comment: The problem is not related to the connection itself, because the documentation says that the BeginSend is after the connection. This means the sockets on both sides are waiting for data!  At this point you have to run a trace to see what side is causing the delay.  But as mentioned before, why does the application care?  It's asynchronous which means the application can just ignore the send stuff if timeout is exceeded.

Comment: Use tasks and optionally await to untangle this mess. You'll find that your code becomes vastly simpler. Who knows, maybe there is a race condition and your code just *thinks* that there is a timeout. A stray timer tick for example.

Comment: Well, I needed a way of detecting a lost connection. I've searched through the web and found that the best way is to actually try and send something.
My application really does care if a data transmission fails. So I should probably switch to a synchronous model.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not enough code to completely diagnose this. You don't even show the declaration of `sendTimeoutflag`. The example isn't self-contained, so there's no way to test it. And you're not clear about exactly what happens (e.g. do you just get the timeout, do you complete a send and still get a timeout, does something else happen?).

That said, I see at least one serious bug in the code, which is your use of the `sendTimeoutflag`. The `SendCallback()` method sets this flag to 1, but it *immediately* sets it back to 0 again (this time without the protection of `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`). Only after it's set the value to 0 does it dispose the timer.

This means that even when you successfully complete the callback, the timeout timer is nearly guaranteed to have no idea and to close the client object anyway.

You can fix this specific issue by moving the assignment `sendTimeoutflag = 0;` to a point after you've actually completed the send operation, e.g. at the end of the callback method. And even then only if you take steps to ensure that the timer callback cannot execute past that point (e.g. wait for the timer's dispose to complete).

Note that even having fixed that specific issue, you may still have other bugs. Frankly, it's not clear why you want a timeout in the first place. Nor is it clear why you want to use lock-free code to implement your timeout logic. More conventional locking (i.e. `Monitor`-based with the `lock` statement) would be easier to implement correctly and would likely not impose a noticeable performance penalty.

And I agree with the suggestion that you would be better-served by using the async/await pattern instead of explicitly dealing with callback methods (but of course that would mean using a higher-level I/O object, since Socket doesn't suppose async/await).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug. You're definitely right about that. It didn't fix the timeout problem, though. Could you point me towards a good example using the "Monitor-based with lock" approach? I'm very new to C# and am learning as I go.
That being said, I probably need to switch to a synchronous model. I need a way of detecting a lost connection and the timeout from synchronous Send() would do just that. I also do care if a transmission fails for any reason.

Comment: I opted for the async method also to avoid creating a special thread for the tcpClient which might have been a bad idea.

Comment: For TCP, you don't need a timeout to detect a lost connection, just the error from a failed send (which will occur regardless of which programming model you're using). TCP supports a "keep-alive" feature which can detect interrupted connections, but the problem with using that is that TCP is resilient to connection interruptions, as long as they occur only when you _don't_ need to send something. Using keep-alive or similar approaches has the net effect of _reducing_ the apparent reliability of the connection, because it exposes connection failures that otherwise would have been recovered from